# if controller not working when I use ${status} == true

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am having a hard time having jemeter working with my if condition

[image]

As you see the above I am checking is status variable which I created in earlier car is true and it is true so I expect this if gets executed but it does not. However as soon as I change it to

[image]

It works fine.

I need these kind of check for sure(for a case like ${status} == false)

Am I missing anything?

** Update **

when I disable interpret regx I can see it works
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

In [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) When you uncheck "Interpret condition as Variable Expression", Javascript is used to evaluate :

> ${status} == true

So it works, but it hurts badly performances.

So instead and as per reference documentation:

> Option 2 : Use a function (${__jexl3()} is advised) to evaluate an expression that must return true or false

So keep "Interpret condition as Variable Expression" checked and use [__jexl3](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function:

> ${__jexl3(${status} == true,)}

This give you:

[image: Good configuration]

Comment: You are awesome